# jQuery caller ID works in queer way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi mega masters of JS and jQuery! I'm somewhat confused by the trick of the "click" function and think that the explanation of the problem is lying in the intricacies of jQuery and JS.

I have a standard binding to a click event

```
$('.add-button').click( function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'superentities/new',
    headers: {
      'X-Transaction': 'GET new superentities',
      'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
    },
    data: {
      entity: event.target.id
    }
  });
});
```

Where I send the caller's ID to the controller. But before that I had a `$(this).id` call in my data hash in place of `event.target.id`. `$(this).id` was always undefined, although Firebug's watcher was like `this->id == some_unundefined_value`.

So is there somebody who can unveil this mystery for me?

Comment: does unundefined mean defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.id` is a native JavaScript method (or a means to access the `id` attribute via plain JavaScript), and works on a node, for example `this`, whereas `$(this)` is a jQuery object 'made from' the native `this` object/node. So, to retrieve the `id` using jQuery:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

in native JavaScript:

```
this.id;
```

The two can't be used interchangeably (the jQuery object won't work with native DOM while still a jQuery object, and the native DOM nodes/objects can't work with jQuery methods).

To retrieve the DOM node from a jQuery object and retrieve the `id`:

```
$(this)[0].id;
```

Comment: thank you master! ))) now I understand that it was a lame question!

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I think you have a scoping issue. $(this) is not referring to $('.add-button') but to $.ajax in your example.

```
$('.add-button').click( function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            entity: id
        }
    });
});
```

Or you could do this:

```
$('.add-button').click( function(event) {
    var self = this; 
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            entity: self.attr('id');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
$(this).attr("id");
```